# Horizontal dislocations in DirectX video rendering

Tags: directx, video-capture

Horizontal dislocations in DirectX video rendering

I'm working on a Qt widget application which using DirectX to do video rendering. The graphics pipeline is from scratch. The video is from DeckLink capture card, and it's 3840x2160p59.94.

But the problem is, the frame have horizontal dislocations. I have no idea what's wrong. Anyone with any discussion, thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: Google for "screen tearing". For example: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-screen-tearing/